# Replace an image inside album photos

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, uiimage

Ih Every body,
well actually I'm taking a picture from my album. I'm drawing on it and then when I'm finish,  I save it into my album. It works perfectly fine. The problem is that of course when I save this new image, the device save it into an other image. What I was wondering is, is it possible to modify an existing image ? like replace it instead to create a new one ? Or if not possible, can I delete the image inside the library and create a new one ?

The perfect way would be working with the URL.

```
// I take the image
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetLibrary assetForURL:asseturl
       resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){NSLog(@"I got my image");}
      failureBlock:^(NSError *error){NSLog(@"Error");}];
```

// Then I replace it with a new one
   ???

Thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried ALAsset setImageData:metadata:completionBlock: ?

Comment: Two methods are interesting :
- setImageData
- writeModifiedImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum
But I think they just re-create a new image. They don't replace the previous one

Comment: the documentation for setImageData says that it writes the image if it is editable, you can check first if it is editable using the editable property

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work 
NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=5F398355-3357-4E29-B51C-9B0B862FE288&ext=JPG"];
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    [data writeToURL:asseturl atomically:YES];

Comment: why are using writeToURL and not setImageData?

Comment: But how setImageData can work ? cause if I understood well, The data is the new image and metadata is is the data you want saved about this image but where do I tell URL of the image I want modify ? Cause I guess I have to target to it

Comment: Use the assetForURL call that you use in your initial question. Inside the resultBlock you have the asset that you want to write

Comment: That is brilliant. But for now it does works because I put nil in metadata. I really don't understand this parameter. What should I put in it ?

Comment: try asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata

Comment: wow I know why it didn't work, the asset is not editable. [asset isEditable] == NO. There anything to do about it ?

Comment: But there is any other way to keep the same image name ? like maybie change the metada data ? Cause It save the new image into the same URL but with a different name. It's kind of confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks a lot to combinatorial, I would never find it without you. 
So the code works only if the app create the asset. This is the method :

```
- (void)replaceImageWithUrl:(NSString *)url withImage:(UIImage*)image
{
   ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
   NSURL *asseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
   [assetLibrary assetForURL:asseturl
              resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
{

           ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
           NSLog(@"Image name : %@",assetRepresentation.filename);

           if([asset isEditable])
           {
               NSLog(@"Asset editable");

               [asset setImageData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) metadata:asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
               {
                   if (error)
                       NSLog(@"error %@",error);
                   else
                       NSLog(@"assetURL %@", assetURL);
           }];
           }
           else
           {
               NSLog(@"Not editable");
           }
       }
      failureBlock:^(NSError *error){NSLog(@"FAILED");
}];
}
```

It seems delete the previous image and create a new one with a new name, It's not optimize but it works...

Answer (score 0):

**Using PHPhotoLibrary you can replace image for particular PHasset from camera roll.**

```
-(void) replaceimagefromcameraroll :(PHAsset*)replaceasset {
    PHAsset *asset = replaceasset;
    NSString *localStr=asset.localIdentifier;
    NSRange range = [localStr rangeOfString:@"/"];
    NSString *newString = [localStr substringToIndex:range.location];
    NSString *appendedString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",@"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=",newString,@"&ext=JPG"];
    NSLog(@"%@ phasset ",appendedString);

    NSURL *ReplaceAsseturl = [NSURL URLWithString:appendedString];

    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[ReplaceAsseturl] options:nil];
    PHAsset *assetReplace = result.firstObject;
    if ([assetReplace canPerformEditOperation:PHAssetEditOperationContent])
    {
        [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:nil completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {

            PHContentEditingOutput *contentEditingOutput = [[PHContentEditingOutput alloc] initWithContentEditingInput:contentEditingInput];

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_imgPreviewView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

            [_imgPreviewView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
            UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            NSData *outputData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, img.scale);

            PHAdjustmentData *adjustmentData = [[PHAdjustmentData alloc] initWithFormatIdentifier:@"AdjustementDataIdentifier" formatVersion:@"1.0" data:outputData];
            contentEditingOutput.adjustmentData = adjustmentData;
            BOOL wrote = [outputData writeToURL:contentEditingOutput.renderedContentURL options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            if (wrote)
            {
                [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
                    PHAssetChangeRequest *request = [PHAssetChangeRequest changeRequestForAsset:asset];
                    request.contentEditingOutput = contentEditingOutput;

                } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                    // console output : 1
                    if (success){
                        NSLog(@"success : %@", @(success));
                        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:ckSuccesReplaceImage];
                    }
                    else{
                        NSLog(@"error : %@", error);
                    }
                }];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

**and ya dont forgot to add this code in Info.plist file**

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access your photo library to let you select a picture.</string>
```